# HTML tags embedded into setText() method's param in SWT?

Tags: html, swt, label, embed, settext

Stackoverflow people !
    I've been trying to embed the HTML tags like color, font etc into the setText() method of the Label component in SWT forms for few days, but it's not working. I'm inspired by the SWING features where we can do that.Please, suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any automatic way to parse HTML tags besides using a Browser widget, but you could get some pretty results by using the StyledText widget. You can apply an array of StyleRanges (which include aspects like font, foreground color, background color, and other things that you would normally use HTML tags for) to the widget in order to get the styles you want. To get it to behave like a Label, call

```
styledText.setEditable(false);
styledText.setEnabled(false);
```

That way users won't be able to select or modify the contents of your widget.

Comment: Thank you Dylan Halperin for your suggestion. But, as I'm trying to embed the HTML tags esp. for ToolTipText of a control like a TextBox (esp for view-level validations), which can not be done in that way. So, please, could you mind to suggest other options. As we know adding additional controls like StyledText into the view could add extra overheads into the object handling in a view at runtime.

Comment: You may want to look into the jface ToolTip implementation. I've used the Default one- it gets you plain text, but you could override the createToolTipContentArea method for your own purposes.